# instanceof established that x is an instance of y. So why is casting necessary when creating a copy of x?

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, casting

This method accepts another object as a parameter and returns true if the object is another HashSet containing the same elements (compare code not shown.) The if-statement uses the **instanceof** operator to establish that yes, object is an instance of HashSet. When creating temp, why cast object as a HashSet?

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof HashSet) {
    HashSet temp = (HashSet) object;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Because there is nothing in the `if` syntax to make `object` **be** a `HashSet`. The `instanceof` test is (strictly speaking) itself unnecessary (since it is also possible, but slower, to catch any casting errors).

Comment: So while HashSet is the superclass, temp object could be a member of the superclass or a member of a subclass. Thus the casting.

Comment: `if (1 == 2)` an `if` tests a boolean condition. It does not, even when used for that purpose by you, imply a change in type.